# SQL Loader Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I have three columns: ProgramID, FeeID, Value.

I need to insert 1000s of records. Not sure how I can create a simple text file for sql loader.

For Example:

```
ProgramID is 1, FeeID is 1 and Value 1.
ProgramID is 1, FeeID is 2 and Value 1.
ProgramID is 1, FeeID is 3 and Value 0.
```

Do I need to create a text file like below:

```
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,0
```

There are 1000s of programs. I was wondering if there is something I can do in one line per program.

Comment: Is you question about how to load data from a flat file? Or how to generate sample/test data in general?